# Extended container background to full screen behind bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to extend the splash-background image on my splash screen to reflect on the entire splash screen. There is a bottomNavigationBar behind which the background doesn't reflect. I need the splash-background to be behind the bottomNavigationBar

Here is my snippet:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash-background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
        color: Colors.white),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
    child: Center(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: _buildLogo())),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomBar(),
)
```

I have tried the following based on other stack posts I read:

Added  extendBody: true,

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  body: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash-background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
        color: Colors.white),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
    child: Center(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: _buildLogo())),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomBar(),
)
```

The above fix isn't working currently.

Here is my current screen :

[image]

The widget _buildBottomBar snippet is below :

```
  Widget _buildBottomBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: _buildCreateAccountButton(context: context)),
            Expanded(
              child: _buildLoginButton(context: context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of what do you have and what do you want pls ?

Comment: Hi @DanielRoldán Kindly check. I need to have the white backgound stretch upto the end of the screen behind the bottomNavigationBar

Comment: If you change your `extendBody: true` nothing happens ?

Comment: Strangely , it doesn't. I even tried re-building the entire app rather than Hot Restart 'R' but doesn't work.

Comment: That's a bit weird, I try it and it works fine, what version of Flutter are you using? Have you tried to clear all the cache ? Try to change the image or put a BottomNavigationBar widget.

Comment: Flutter : 3.10.1

Comment: I have added addiitonal code. The widget _buildBottomBar code snippet that is linked to the one facing issue.

Comment: I am doing your same exercise and I don't have any problem concerning the background, how are the buttons you are using?

Comment: Didn't understand your question regarding buttons.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the thing is that my background even putting your same BottomAppBar, is behind and it works, I don't know if it's something related to your buttons or your own background.

Comment: Understood. Let me troubleshoot both then.

Comment: So it solved. I changed this line to : color: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255) using a slider to a checkered area. I can see the background now. This I believe to be the transparency of the _buildBottomBar ?